# Event dup checking applied even though Event configured to allow dup emails

Tags: civievent

Civi 5.4 on CentOS server, PHP 7.4 - some patrons and staff report getting message 'participant is already registered' (from Register for Event) or 'looks like you are already registered..' for events where the 'allow_same_participant_emails'  flag is ON (set to 1). When I test it I do not get the message. Is this a browser caching issue with participant? I also thought of using the patch mentioned in CRM-7604 using build_form hook but cannot access patch from archive (https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-7604).
 The events are all configured correctly to allow dup email registrants.

Comment: I am not sure if this is *the* answer but, there's a problem with EventInfo.php in CRM/Event/Page.   Unlike in Register Event Participant, there is just one error/info message put up in EventInfo.php - if an Event is full, AND the registrant is already registered, whether or not the event allows duplicate emails. the message about being already registered is shown, and NOT the event full message.  The fix is simple; starting at line 323,

Comment: I  found what i think is a problem in CRM/Event/Page/EventInfo.php - if an event is Full AND the contact/user is already registered in it, it only displays the message about the user being already registered. I will add the fix in a following comment here.

Comment: if ($values['event']['allow_same_participant_emails']) {
              $registerUrl = CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/event/register',
              "reset=1&id={$values['event']['id']}&cid=0"
            );
            if ($statusMessage == ''){
              $statusMessage = ts('It looks like you are already registered for this event.'). ' ' . ts('You can <a href="%1">register again</a>.', array(1 => $registerUrl));
            }